# Assistance Needed with Conditional Routing in Dialogflow CX

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, agent, dialogflow-cx

am currently working on my Dialogflow CX flow and I need guidance on how to proceed. Specifically, I am trying to create conditional routes based on the results from my MongoDB database. I have successfully implemented a webhook that connects my MongoDB database to Dialogflow CX, allowing the chat to display results based on user queries.

At this point, I am looking to create a path that checks the database results and directs the conversation to either "LoadExist" or "LoadDoesntExist" pages. Additionally, I need to incorporate further conditions, where the routing is determined not only by the existence of data but also by the presence of specific elements such as "DNU" or "General."

Could you please assist me in creating these conditional routes? I am currently stuck at this point and any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.